# Display random string value from array as asterisks

Tags: c#, console

I am making a program for a hangman game that picks a random word from a text file of words and then asks the user to guess each letter of the word. Each letter in the word is displayed with an asterisk and when the user makes a correct guess the actual letter is then displayed. After the word is guessed it will then display the number of times missed and ask the user if they want to guess another word. 
I have the asterisks hard coded but I would like the asterisks to be the same length of the random word chosen from the text file. I am not sure how I would do this
Any help would be appreciated.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] guessed = new char[26];
        char[] testword = "******".ToCharArray();
        char[] word = RandomLine().ToCharArray();
        char[] copy = word;
        char guess;

        char playAgain;

        int amountMissed = 0, index = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(testword);
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I have picked a random word on animals");
            Console.WriteLine("Your task is to guess the correct word");
            while (testword != word)
            {

                    Console.Write("Please enter a letter to guess: ");

                    guess = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    bool right = false;
                    for (int j = 0; j < copy.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (copy[j] == guess)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Your guess is correct.");
                            testword[j] = guess;
                            guessed[index] = guess;
                            index++;
                            right = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (right != true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your guess is incorrect.");
                        amountMissed++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        right = false;

                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(testword);

                }
                Console.WriteLine($"The word is {copy}. You missed {amountMissed} times.");

            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to guess another word? Enter y or n: ");
            playAgain = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        } while (playAgain == 'y' || playAgain == 'Y');

        Console.WriteLine("Good-Bye and thanks for playing my Hangman game.");


    }

    public static string RandomLine()
    {
        try
        {
            // store text file in an array and return a random value
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Intel\\Advanced1.csv");
            Random rand = new Random();
            return lines[rand.Next(lines.Length)];
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the coded word (with asterisks) with same length as word, you could use

```
char[] testword = new string('*',word.Length).ToCharArray();
```

Making few other corrections in your code

```
char[] guessed = new char[26];
char guess;
char playAgain;

int amountMissed = 0, index = 0;

do
{

    char[] word = RandomLine().ToCharArray();  // Change :This needs to be inside the loop so that new random word could be selected user selects to continue the game
    char[] testword = new string('*',word.Length).ToCharArray();  // Change : Reordered initilization of word and testword so that we could generate testword with same length as original
    char[] copy = word;

    Console.WriteLine(testword);
    Console.WriteLine("I have picked a random word on animals");
    Console.WriteLine("Your task is to guess the correct word");

    while (!testword.SequenceEqual(word)) // Change : Comparison of arrays
    {

            Console.Write("Please enter a letter to guess: ");

            guess = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            bool right = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < copy.Length; j++)
            {
               if (copy[j] == guess)
               {
                 Console.WriteLine("Your guess is correct.");
                 testword[j] = guess;
                 guessed[index] = guess;
                 index++;
                 right = true;
               }
             }
             if (right != true)
             {
                Console.WriteLine("Your guess is incorrect.");
                amountMissed++;
             }
             else
             {
                right = false;
             }
             Console.WriteLine(testword);

          }
          Console.WriteLine($"The word is {copy}. You missed {amountMissed} times.");

          Console.WriteLine("Do you want to guess another word? Enter y or n: ");
          playAgain = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        } while (playAgain == 'y' || playAgain == 'Y');

        Console.WriteLine("Good-Bye and thanks for playing my Hangman game.");
```

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool found = false;
        string originalWord = "test";
        char[] word = originalWord.ToCharArray();
        char[] asteriskedWord = new string('*', word.Length).ToCharArray();
        while (found == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(asteriskedWord);
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input.Length != 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your input can be only one char.");
            }
            else
            {
                char c = char.Parse(input);
                for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (word[i] == c)
                    {
                        asteriskedWord[i] = c;
                        word[i] = '*';
                        int missingCharsAmount = asteriskedWord.Count(x => x == '*');
                        Console.WriteLine("Correct, missing " + missingCharsAmount + " chars.");
                        if (missingCharsAmount == 0)
                        {
                            found = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```